# Is List<T> a constant, an expression parameter, or something else in Expression Tree?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Let's say I have this lambda expression that I want to write an expression Tree on:

```
query.Where(d => (allCk && d.FacilityId == facilityId) //1.
      ||
     (!allCk && allSelected && d.FacilityId == facilityId  && !ids.Contains(d.Id)) //2.
      ||
     (!allCk && !allSelected && ids.Contains(d.Id))) //3.
```

This is how I've managed to write it: For brevity, I'll only show the second condition, which the most complex of all `(!allCk && allSelected && d.FacilityId == facilityId  && !ids.Contains(d.Id))`.

```
private Expression<Func<Documents, bool>> GetDocumentsPredicate(
        int facilityId, bool allCk, bool allSelected, List<int> ids)
{
  ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Documents), "d");

  var listExpr1 = new List<Expression>();
  listExpr1.Add(Expression.IsFalse(Expression.Constant(allCk)));  //allCk
  listExpr1.Add(Expression.Constant(allSelected));                //allSelected

  var facilityParam = Expression.Constant(facilityId);            //facility
  Expression facilityIdProp = Expression.Property(pe, "FacilityId");
  Expression facilityIdEql = Expression.Equal(facilityIdProp, facilityParam);
  listExpr1.Add(facilityIdEql);

  //This is where I'm having trouble... Is ids a parameter or a constant???
  //Assuming it's a parameter...

  ParameterExpression peIds = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<int>), "ids");
  Expression listContains = Expression.Call(
           pIds,
           typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains"),
           Expression.Property(pe, "Id"));
  listExpr1.Add(Expression.Call(peIds, listContains, Expression.Property(pe, "Id"))); 
  var exp1 = listExpr1
             .Skip(1)
             .Aggregate(listExpr1[0], Expression.AndAlso);

  //...

}
```

I'm getting an error at this line: `listExpr1.Add(Expression.Call(pIds, listContains, Expression.Property(pe, "Id")));` // Cannot convert 'Linq.Expression.ParameterExpression' to 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'`. So, it's complaining about the **pIds**.

So What is ids in here, a constant, a parameter, or something else?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

This is how I wrote the entire method

```
private Expression<Func<Documents, bool>> GetDocumentsPredicate(
    int facilityId, bool allCk, bool allSelected, List<int> ids)
{
  ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Document), "d");
  Expression constIds = Expression.Constant(ids);
  Expression allCkParam = Expression.Constant(allCk);
  Expression allSelectedParam = Expression.Constant(allSelected);

  Expression listContains = Expression.Call(
           constIds,
           typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains"),
           Expression.Property(pe, "Id"));

  /*(allCk && d.FacilityId == facilityId) ==> exp0*/
  var facilityParam = Expression.Constant(facilityId);


  Expression facilityIdProp = Expression.Property(pe, "FacilityId");
  Expression facilityIdEql = Expression.Equal(facilityIdProp, facilityParam);

  Expression exp0 = Expression.AndAlso(allCkParam, facilityIdEql);

/*(!allCk && allSelected && d.FacilityId == facilityId && !ids.Contains(d.Id))) 
  ==> exp1 */
  var listExpr1 = new List<Expression>();
  listExpr1.Add(Expression.IsFalse(allCkParam));
  listExpr1.Add(allSelectedParam);
  listExpr1.Add(facilityIdEql);
  listExpr1.Add(Expression.IsFalse(listContains));

  var exp1 = listExpr1
            .Skip(1)
            .Aggregate(listExpr1[0], Expression.AndAlso);


   /* (!allCk && !allSelected && ids.Contains(d.Id)) ==> exp2 */
   var listExpr2 = new List<Expression>();
   listExpr2.Add(Expression.IsFalse(allCkParam));
   listExpr2.Add(Expression.IsFalse(allSelectedParam));
   listExpr1.Add(listContains);

   var exp2 = listExpr2
            .Skip(1)
            .Aggregate(listExpr2[0], Expression.AndAlso);

   var listExpr = new List<Expression> { exp0, exp1, exp2 };
   var exp = listExpr
            .Skip(1)
            .Aggregate(listExpr[0], Expression.OrElse);

    var expr = 
              Expression.Lambda<Func<Document, bool>>(exp, 
              new ParameterExpression[] { pe });
    return expr;
 }
```

This is the result I'm getting when hovering over the returned value

```
d => (((False AndAlso (d.FacilityId == 1)) 
     OrElse 
     (((IsFalse(False) AndAlso False) AndAlso (d.FacilityId == 1)) 
        AndAlso 
        IsFalse(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]).Contains(d.Id)))) 
     OrElse 
    ((IsFalse(False) AndAlso IsFalse(False)) 
        AndAlso 
        value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]).Contains(d.Id)))
```

A simple test with this statement `var count = query.Count();` produces an exception: `Unknown LINQ expression of type 'IsFalse'`.

Comment: If you want the expression to use the `List<int> ids` that was passed in to `GetDocumentsPredicate()`, it's a constant as far as the caller of the final expression is concerned. If he's not providing it at that time, it's not a parameter. `Expression<Func<Device, bool>>` has one parameter, a `Device`.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the question; you have the lambda, so why not simply convert it directly to an expression tree? Make the compiler do the work.

Comment: You're saying you're getting an error on `pIds` but your method nowhere defines a local or formal of that name. This makes it hard for us to diagnose the problem. Can you include a *minimal example* that actually reproduces the problem?

Comment: This whole thing looks like a misedit; like you were trying to extract the call factory to its own statement and messed up in the editor. Why are there two lines that both attempt to make what looks like the same call expressions?

Comment: @EricLippert, I'm learning how expression tree works. There are many instances where I don't know the columns to filter out. You are right, I was stuck in the Where clause that why I extracted to its own method so that I can deal with different cases, not always knowing all the conditions at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ids` is not a parameter, as far as the expression tree is concerned, because it is not passed to `Func<...>`. The list of `id`s against which you need to match is built into the structure of the expression, hence `Expression.Constant` is the proper way to handle it.

However, that's not the whole story: since `ids` is a reference type, only a reference to it is going into the structure of the expression. Therefore, if you decide to change the content of the list after constructing the expression, the meaning of the `ids.Contains` is going to change.

If this is not the effect that you would like to achieve, make a copy of the list:

```
Expression constIds = Expression.Constant(ids.ToList());
```

Comment: I see. So for something like: `(x, I) => `, x and I would be expression Parameters. Make sense.

Comment: I'm getting just a problem with the `Expression.IsFalse()` method. Please see edit.

Comment: @Richard77 I would replace all calls to `Expression.IsFalse(blah)` with calls to `Expression.Not(blah)` and see if the system would take it better.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. It's so hard to find a comprehensive tutorial online on Linq Expression Tree. There are plenty of one-page tutorial, but nothing deeper. A link or a resource that teach this matter will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Richard77 You are right, this stuff is described mostly through web tutorials. I got started with it after reading a few pages about it in the [LINQ Pocket Reference](https://www.amazon.com/LINQ-Pocket-Reference-Implement-Applications/dp/0596519249/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1496244967&sr=8-1&keywords=LINQ+Pocket+Reference) book, but most of my understanding came from developing with this technology for several years. Eric's expertise is even deeper - he worked on the team that developed this stuff at Microsoft. I can highly recommend his blog, too.

Answer (score 5):

Let's sum up. You are getting an overload resolution error on this call:

```
Expression.Call(peIds, listContains, Expression.Property(pe, "Id"))
```

`peIds` is of type `ParameterExpression`.
`listContains` is of type `Expression`.
The third argument is of type `MemberExpression`.

Now, look at the list of overloads to `Expression.Call`. None of those match these three arguments.

The compiler's best guess is that you're trying to call this one:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324092(v=vs.110).aspx

hence the error: that the first argument is not a method info.

Choose which overload you wish to call and then supply arguments of those types.

But frankly I don't see why you're doing this at all; I don't see what portion of the original lambda this is intended to represent. Why is the line not simply `listExpr1.Add(listContains);` ???

Comment: There's so few comprehensive tutorial on the topic, I didn't find anything even on Pluralsight.